# How can I get an output by click on a select2 element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I want to get an output when I click on my select2 box. Not when I select something. Already just the click on the element:

```js
$(document).ready(

function () {
    var configParamsObj = {
        placeholder: 'Select an option...', 
        minimumResultsForSearch: 3 
    };
    $("#singleSelectExample").select2(configParamsObj);
});

$( "#singleSelectExample" ).focus(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .focus() called." );
});

$("#singleSelectExample").click(function(){
    alert("The select2 was clicked.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.css">


<body>
  <body>Single select example
    <div class="selectRow">
        <select id="singleSelectExample">
            <option></option><!-- Needed to show X image to clear the select -->
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="5">Option 5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

I tried to to get an `alert` with my click-function and also with a focus-function. But it is not working. No output

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: There is no output, why?

Comment: When I click on the select the alert fires (please don't use alerts without blurring an input afterwards, use console.log) What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: you must necessarily use the version 3.5? Or you can use 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach an `open`/`opening` event handler to your Select2 element:

1) with Select2 [version 3.5](http://select2.github.io/select2/#documentation#events):

```
$("#singleSelectExample").on("select2-open", function(e) {
     console.log("open", e);
});
```

A fiddle (vers. for Select2 3.5): https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/wp59L8n7/

2) with Select2 [version 4.0](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events):

```
$("#singleSelectExample").on("select2:open", function(e) {
     console.log("open", e);
});
```

A fiddle (vers. for Select2 4.0): https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/7bpj7asq/